# Express Multer - req.file returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am trying to upload image file via multer and I dont understand why req.file returns undefined
I have set up form encType to mulipart/form-data, input name matches with the upload.single() parameter. I have also tried to set header multipart/form-data via axios but also did not help

auth.js

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-");
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + fileName);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (
      file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
      file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
      file.mimetype == "image/jpeg"
    ) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
      return cb(new Error("Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!"));
    }
  },
});
router.post(
  "/changeAvatar",
  upload.single("avatar"),
  userAuth,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      console.log(req.file);
      const url =
        req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + "/public/" + req.file.filename;
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, { image: url });
      res.json({ user });
    } catch (err) {
      res.json({ err });
    }
  }
);
```

react form

```
                      <form
                        onSubmit={handlePostAvatar}
                        encType="multipart/form-data"
                      >
                        <input
                          // style={{ display: "none" }}
                          type="file"
                          name="avatar"
                          id="avatar"
                          // ref={avatarFileRef}
                          onChange={changeHandle}
                        />
                        <button style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Save</button>
                      </form>
```

post request

```
  const handlePostAvatar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/auth/changeAvatar");
      console.log(res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: You're not actually sending anything because you missed the payload argument const { data } = await axios.post("https://httpbin.org/post", e.target);